# In IE, tbody shrinks when there's no cell having a complete cell length of text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a table and using JQuery to append the data into the table. The thing is that if I create one row of data but no cell has a complete length of text of the cell, the tbody will shrink. But if there's at least one cell/row that meets the requirement, then all rows in tbody looks ok. Note that the problem only appears in IE! Chrome does not have this problem!

I cannot attach picture because I don't have enough reputation yet. If you need code, I can put it here.

Comment: use &nbsp; when content is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I tried. But for some reason, when it comes to last '&nbsp;', a letter will go to next line but if I delete it, it still shrinks a little bit